# Compare SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> C#

Tags: c#, linq

I asked similar question here , I am wondering  how you can achieve same result with LINQ

PREVIOUS QUESTION

[Compare Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029244/compare-dictionarystring-listobject)

**Rules**

Get values from dic2 where key match but values does not match or key is missing in dic2.
Don’t need to iterate through dic2 for missing/different values in dic1.

**LINQ CODE**

can result and missinkeu can combin**strong text**e in one?

```
private void Compare(SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic1, SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic2)
 {

            var result=   from c in dic1
                          where dic2.ContainsKey((c.Key) && !dic2[c.key]Equals(c.Value)
                          select p.Value;
      

            var missingkey =from c in dic1
                          where !dic2.ContainsKey((c.Key) 
                          select p.Value;
 }
```

Comment: What are you asking?  "Can result and missingkey can combine in one?"  Can these queries be combined into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean:

```
        var result = from pair in dic1
                     where !dic2.ContainsKey(pair.Key)
                        || !dic2[pair.Key].Equals(pair.Value)
                     select pair.Value;
```

when the key is there the second match is tested. Note however, that this will *only* (as written) do a reference test on the lists - it won't compare individual elements. It is hard to tell if that is what you mean since the code example in the linked post is... "unclear" (in that it attempts to add `foo` as value for `List<foo>`).

If you need to test the individual values:

```
        var result = from pair in dic1
                     where !dic2.ContainsKey(pair.Key)
                     || !dic2[pair.Key].SequenceEqual(pair.Value)
                     select pair.Value;
```

(which assumes a sensible `Equals` implementation on `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to write this as a loop instead.  Here's how I would implement it:

```
static void Compare(SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic1, SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic2)
{
    var result = new List<List<foo>>();
    var missingkey = new List<List<foo>>();

    foreach (var kvp in dic1)
    {
        var value = default(List<foo>);
        if (dic2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value))
        {
            if (kvp.Value.SequenceEqual(value))
                result.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            missingkey.Add(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you insist on using LINQ to do this, here's one way to do it:

```
static void Compare(SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic1, SortedDictionary<string, List<foo>> dic2)
{
    const string isIgnored = null, isResult = "result", isMissingkey = "missingkey";
    var combined = (from kvp in dic1
                    group kvp.Value by (dic2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)
                                            ? kvp.Value.SequenceEqual(dic2[kvp.Key])
                                                  ? isResult
                                                  : isIgnored
                                            : isMissingkey) into g
                    where g.Key != isIgnored
                    select g)
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

    // result in combined["result"]
    // missingkey in combined["missingkey"]
}
```